# Problems with reading text file - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I’m trying to create a Java String[] from the content of a file.

The code is:

```
private String[] arr;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public String[] readfile (String fileName) {
   try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

      while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
          list.add(str);
      }         

      arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      try {
         if (br != null){
            br.close(); 
         }
      } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   return arr;
}
```

The function apparently works. In fact, the variable arr contains the content of file.

However, after this line, `arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);` the function doesn’t return `arr`. I get `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you check what number is `list.size()` returning?

Comment: I don't think it is the code you have provided that is causing this exception. Can you provide the entire stack trace please.

Comment: @wtsang02 It doens't matter what the size if the list is. The `toArray()` method creates a new array if the given array is to small to fit the list in.

Comment: Please post actual code that demonstrates the issue (See: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). The code you have posted can not generate that exception.

Comment: If I initialize the arraylist and I put a simply `return arr` in the method, it works. I have problems when I use BufferedReader. For that reason, I thought  it was the problem. Well, I’ll review the rest of the code. Thanks for your comments and sorry for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the code I had provided was causing the exception.  The problem is related to try catch block and variable scope.

Here, `arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);` the variabe `arr` contains all lines of file. However, in this line `return arr;` the content is null;

For that, when I initialize the array and I put a simply `return arr` in the method, it works. In this case, I don’t have any try catch block.